# What does WaitForChild and FindFirstChild mean in Roblox?

Tags: lua, parent-child, roblox

Watched several tutorials about these two... What are they even called? Still can't completely understand what they do. Can someone explain it like you would to a non-programmer?

Comment: stop watching video tutorials, read the documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference

https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/Instance/WaitForChild

> Returns the child of the Instance with the given name. If the child
> does not exist, it will yield the current thread until it does.
>
> If the timeOut parameter is specified, this function will return nil
> and time out after timeOut seconds elapsing without the child being
> found.

https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/Instance/FindFirstChild

> Returns the first child of the Instance found with the given name. If
> no child exists with the given name, this function returns nil. If the
> optional recursive argument is true, this function searches all
> descendants rather than only the immediate children of the Instance.
> Use this function if your code cannot guarantee the existence of an
> object with a given name.

Watching video tutorials is pointless if you do not refer to a manual.

Comment: In addition to the API reference manuals, there are also on-boarding tutorials : https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/onboarding